# Counting the variables that occur most often next to each other

Tags: r, find-occurrences

I'm working with a large database and I want to see which variables are most often found in each other's environment (i.e. in the same row). There can be more than 20 variables in a row and I don't know all of them.

Here is an example:

```
  var1 <- c("x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "y")
  var2 <- c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "e", "e", "g", "h")
  data <- data.frame(cbind(var1, var2))
```

The result should look like this:

```
|frequent contacts|n|
x&a 2
x&b 2
y&e 2
x&c 1
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
with(data, table(paste(var1, var2, sep = "&")))  |>
  as.data.frame()

#   Var1 Freq
# 1  x&a    2
# 2  x&b    2
# 3  x&c    1
# 4  x&d    1
# 5  y&e    2
# 6  y&g    1
# 7  y&h    1
```

Comment: This seems a great solution. Can it be made to work with any number of variables (without NAs)?

Comment: Yes, you can have more variables: `table(paste(var1, var2, var3, sep = "&"))`

Comment: I tried it with five variables and unfortunately it also reports NAs. (It would be important to omit them.) And one more question: is it possible to include, for example, not only twenty variables at a time, but also two or three or four variables?

Comment: Easiest to omit them first from the data